# How to use 2to3 tool in windows?

Tags: python, python-2to3

I tried to modify the sintax using 2to3 tool by running command

```
python C:\Python32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py neo4j.py
```

and got the output

[image]

When opening neo4j.py however I noticed there hasn't been anything changed. Below is the block of code where changes (accoridng to output) should be made:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
try:
    from urllib.parse import quote
except ImportError:
    from urllib import quote
try:
    from . import rest, batch, cypher
except ImportError:
    import rest, batch, cypher
except ValueError:
    import rest, batch, cypher

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Does anyone know how to use 2to3 tool properly in order to port/change the code to v3.2?

Comment: The new version (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2neo) of py2neo claims Python 3 compatibility out of the box.

Comment: I tried this version but it doesn't work

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to use the `-w` flag to actually write the changes:

```
python C:\Python32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py -w neo4j.py
```

See the [2to3.py documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/2to3.html).

Comment: I just get invalis sytax on the letter C:

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS What do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

*As an addition to the accepted answer,*

Copy this line to `C:\python32\Scripts\2to3.bat`:

```
@python %~dp0..\tools\scripts\2to3.py %*
```

After that you'll be able to use

```
2to3 -w neo4j.py
```