# How to install graphics.py on Ubuntu 12.04 for Python3.2

Tags: python, tkinter, ubuntu-12.04

I am a beginning python enthusiast, self-teaching myself from the book of John Zell.
I reached the point where I need to learn about objects and about graphics. So, 
I followed instructions and saved graphics.py into /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

However, I got his:

> > > import graphics
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/**init**.py", line 40, in 
> > >           import _tkinter
> > >       ImportError: No module named _tkinter

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/graphics.py", line 151, in 
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/**init**.py", line 42, in 
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package')
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/graphics.py", line 153, in 
    import Tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named Tkinter

I checked and it seems that tkinter is installed. 
Please kindly help me to go around it, because I dont know what to do next.

Thank you so much!

Comment: That script is written for Python 2. Python 2 scripts usually aren't compatible with Python 3, so you'll need to install Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem: `usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/graphics.py`

```
line 153, in import Tkinter as tk
```

In Python 3+, Tkinter is imported as tkinter. Simply edit the graphics.py file to `import tkinter as tk`.
Note: As Bender stated, it will probably be easier to continue learning with python 2.*, as you may encounter further issues in the future.

Comment: I doubt that's the only problem if the script is written for Python 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. I tried editing graphics.py file and importing it in Python 3. It did not work. Then I tried importing this module using Python 2.7. It worked, but I am frustrated I couldn't make Python 3 work for me. I really appreciate your time and efforts guys!

Comment: If you really want to get it working in 3, try running 2to3 on the graphics.py file. See http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/2to3.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071037/how-to-use-2to3-tool-in-windows