# Trying to import a module containing old print statements into new python 3.6

Tags: python

I am trying to import the `paraview.simple` module from Paraview 5.2 into the new Python 3.6.2 using IDLE. Unfortunately it appears this module is using the old `print` statement as suggested by this error message:

```
>>> import paraview.simple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    import paraview.simple
  File "C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.0.1\lib\paraview-5.0\site-packages\paraview\__init__.py", line 129
    print text
             ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I really want to use this version of python? There are other modules I wish to use alongside paraview.simple which are only compatible with the *latest* version of python. How can I circumvent this minor print issue and import the modules I need?

Comment: Would you want to convert the paraview.simple module from version 2 to 3? If yes, then you can use - "2to3". A program to convert python2 code to python3. Link - https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071037/how-to-use-2to3-tool-in-windows
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458011/how-to-use-2to3-properly-for-python

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the question might not be relevant anymore since paraview hasn't been supported for long time (at least there haven't been any pull requests since 2017 https://github.com/Kitware/ParaView/pulls).

For those who still want to use it there is a solution as pointed by @Shashank in the comments: just convert it from python2 to python3 using 2to3 or similar tool.