# django site urls whose are not under site-packages

Tags: django

Lets assume you have a django website svn directory which is not under site-packages. 
Whenever i run:

```
mysyper_dir/whatever_module/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888
```

and then connect, I realize that my request are still handled by the python files in:

```
....../site-packages/whatever_module/
```

while I can see the prints of

```
mysyper_dir/whatever_module/setting.py
```

from my server console.
is there a way to tell django that, every "non-framework" files it will ever need are in the "mysyper_dir/whatever_module" directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these are Django specific (Python actually already handles this) but there's a couple of things you could do. You could set the environment variable [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), or you could add directories to [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). You can find more about where modules are located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069925/how-where-does-python-look-for-modules).

If you are looking to have things *just* apply to Django, then adding to sys.path might be your best bet. You could try something weird like modifying `manage.py` and adding command line arguments after the `#!/usr/bin/env python` but that's uncharted territory for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what seems totally counterintuitiev to me is that i'm running the manage.py runserver from one directory, but the request are handled by another directory ? how in the hell does the django server decides where is the server root ? is there some equivalent to the DocumentRoot/serverRoot of apache ?

Comment: Not sure why it is counter-intuitive. The Django source is in yet another directory, and the Python source is in a third.

Comment: The entire website is in a folder XXX, so whenever I run "XXX/manage.py runserver YYYYYY", I expect it to behave in the same way as if I had told apache the the serverroot was in the XXX folder. How does django server decides where to look for server files ? I haven't find any option in the doc

Comment: It doesn't "decide", not really. `manage.py` basically adds the current directory to `sys.path`. After that, Python just looks for modules in `sys.path`.

Comment: but when i print each element of my sys.path I can see XXX/ folder nut not the one from which python is running files...

Comment: Ok, actually you gave me the answer, removing the complete site-packages from my sys.path resolved the problem...